# Using curl to fetch SSO enabled page content

Tags: perl, curl

I am trying to fetch the contents of confluence page by using curl hit from within a perl script.

```
print `curl -u username\@random.com:password https://confluence.random.com/confluence/random/path`;
```

The page is protected behind a SSO page.
The confluence page redirects to a SSO page where it asks for the username/password.

My sample output looks like this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   819  100   819    0     0   4803      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  138k

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>302 Redirect to SSO Server for login</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Redirect to SSO Server for login</h1>
    <p>The requested resource has been temporarily moved <a href="https://login.abcd.com:443/oam/server/osso_login?Site2pstoreToken=v1.2~EBB57BDE3BB174465E~C...">here</a>.</p>
    </body></html>
```

Any idea how to get around this restriction?

Although I would prefer to do it on the server side - 
I have tried using JSONP approach for scraping the data from client side as well - however, this approach also didn't yield much.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with curl. I'm unsure what you mean about doing it from the server side; if you have access to the server then you can do anything you like. Why not simply log in using `LWP`?

Comment: `-u` is only for basic authentication, which isn't applicable here (302 instead of 401 with specific headers). Most login scripts set a cookie that gives access to other pages. You would need to submit the user name and password to the login page, extract the cookie, and pass in the cookie along future requests. WWW::Mechanize facilitates this.

Comment: You definitely want `-L` to follow the redirect.